# javaの引数の引渡し作用についてよくわかりません

Tags: java

質問が連投になって大変申し訳ないのですが。
javaを学習中でありますが、引数の引渡し作用がいまいちわかりません。

```
class CallByValue{
public static void main(String args[]){
    int i   = 5;
    int j[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("abcde");

    display(i, j, sb);

    a(i, j, sb);

    display(i, j, sb);
}

static void a(int i, int j[], StringBuffer sb) {
    i = 7;
    j[0] = 11;
    sb.append("fghij");
}
static void display(int i, int j[], StringBuffer sb) {
    System.out.println(i);
    for(int index = 0; index < j.length; index++)
        System.out.println(j[index] + " ");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(sb);
}}
```

このコードで出されるメッセージは
5
1 
2 
3 
4

abcde
5
11 
2 
3 
4

abcdefghij
です。
main()で記述されている diplay()で一度表示して a()でstatic void a()の値を戻して変えて次の display()に表示といった順にメッセージを表示していると考えているのですが

```
static void a(int i, int j[], StringBuffer sb) {
    i = 7;
    j[0] = 11;
    sb.append("fghij");
}
```

このコードをみると　7 11 2 3 4 fghijとなるのではないかと思います。

i = 7と書いているのにどうして i=5のままで出されるのでしょうか
またsb.append("fghij")と書かれているのにどうして abcdefghijと出されるのでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: もうちょっとで何かつかめそうなのですが　もしよければ int i = 5を変更して別の値に変わるコードをどなたか教えていただけませんか。

Comment: 例えですがint i=1 は　i という箱に１というものが入っていて、その箱の中身を引数として値を渡した場合箱の元の中は変更できない。 j[0]=11は　jという箱に{}という箱が入っていて、その箱に0,1,2,3という物が入っていて引数として渡した場合箱の中は（｛｝という箱)は変更できないけど‌​その｛｝という箱の中身は変更できるから可能　というイメージでいいのでしょうか？ –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java の関数は値渡しになります。関数を呼び出す側から変数が渡されているのではなく値が渡されています。

```
public class Foo {
    public static void foo() {
        int i = 0; // (1) i に 0 という値が格納される
        bar(i);    // (2) i の値が bar の引数として渡される
    }
    public static void bar(int n) {
        n = 1;     // (3) 値が渡されているだけなので変数の中身を更新しても意味が無い
    }
}
```

違う変数名を使うとイメージ湧きやすいと思います。
ただし値渡しとはいっても渡される物が何かによって初心者の方が躓く結果が現れます。
Java の Object を継承したインスタンスも同様に値が渡されます。

```
class Boo {
    int n = 0;
    public void setValue(int n) { this.n = n; }
    public int getValue() { return this.n; }
}

public class Foo {
    public static void foo() {
        Boo b = new Boo(); // (1) b に Boo のインスタンスが格納される
        b.setValue(0);     // (2) 中身の値を更新する
        bar(b);            // (3) インスタンスという値が渡される
    }
    public static void bar(Bar b) {
        b.setValue(1);     // (4) b が変更されるのではなく
                           //     b から辿る事が出来る n が更新される。
        b = new Boo();     // (5) 変数を上書きしても (4) は壊れない。
    }
}
```

関数 foo が生成した b を引数経由で関数 bar に渡して更新し、関数 foo に戻す事は出来ませんが、b の中身を更新する事は出来ます。
これはインスタンスだけでなく、例えば配列を渡して配列を丸ごと書き換えて戻す事は出来ないけれど、配列の中身を変えて戻すことは出来る、という意味と同じです。

上記の例だと i の値を変えても意味は無いですが、a から辿れる StringBuffer の中身を自身で更新する事は出来るのです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
申し訳ありません。
”関数を呼び出す側から変数が渡されているのではなく値が渡されています。”というのと
”値が渡されているだけなので変数の中身を更新しても意味が無い”
というのがよくわかりません。

戻すことと更新する事。
配列を渡して配列を丸ごと書き換えて戻すことはできないけれど配列の中身を変えて戻すことはできるとありますが
違いがいまいちわかりません。申し訳ありません。

Comment: Java では関数の引数に変数を渡した場合、変数の参照が渡っている訳ではなく値が渡っているのです。上記の私の1つ目の例で言うと、変数 i が bar に渡る時、値は n という変数に渡されます。なので n を幾ら更新しても元の i に値が戻らないのです。それとは異なり、下の例はインスタンスが渡っています。インスタンスは言ってしまえば住所録の様な物です。住所録が値としてわたり、関数 bar はその住所に書かれている先の値を書き換えたのです。foo の中での住所とbarの中での住所は一致しているはず(というか住所は世界で1つしかない)ので期待した通り書き変わる訳です。

Comment: 例えですがint i=1 は　i という箱に１というものが入っていて、その箱の中身を引数として値を渡した場合箱の元の中は変更できない。
j[0]=11は　jという箱に{}という箱が入っていて、その箱に0,1,2,3という物が入っていて引数として渡した場合箱の中は（｛｝という箱)は変更できないけどその｛｝という箱の中身は変更できるから可能　というイメージでいいのでしょうか？

Comment: はい。その認識で大丈夫です。ただしこの値と表現される物は言語によって異なってきます。値のどれがプリミティブでどれがプリミティブでないか把握しておいた方が良いです。

Answer (score 1):

javaで扱うデータ型の種類としては大きく「値型」と「参照型」の２種類があって、
例えばint のような数値を表すような基本的なタイプはその値をそのまま保持しているので「値型」と呼びます。
対して、クラス(フィールドやらクラスの情報やらなんやら)や配列(型の情報、それぞれの要素の値、長さなどを持つ)のような複雑な値を持つものは、そのままを保持という形にすると扱いが煩雑なので、
代表→｛実際の内容、フィールドやらメソッドやらの部分｝
のように｛…｝の本体部分を参照するものを持って扱うようにします。
こういうタイプのモノを参照型と呼びます。
（もちろん「代表」→ {int}の様にint 型を表現するとか全てのタイプを参照型にすることはできるでしょうがメモリを余分に消費します）

今、関数の呼び出しで値型の変数と参照型の変数を渡したとすると、
値型の場合は「値」そのものがコピーして渡されます。
参照型の場合は、「代表」がコピーされて渡されます。
関数側では、
値がコピーされたモノを扱っても、それはコピーですからオリジナルには影響ありません。
「代表」が渡された場合「代表」それ自体はコピーですが、指している参照先である本体部分は同じですから
「代表」を使って本体部分を操作するので、元の内容が変更されます。
「代表」自体はコピーなので値型と同じくこれ自体がもし変更できるとしてもオリジナルの「代表」を変更することはできませんが、指している中身自体は同じなのでメソッド呼び出しなどの操作で中身の変更ができます。

必ずしも正確な説明では無いかも知れないですが、そんな感じです。

---

`int j[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4};`
は、int 型の要素１，２，３，４を持つ配列に`j`と名前を付けるということです。
先の説明で言う、`j`が「代表」ということになります。
ｊ→｛[１，２，３，４], length, ...}
そこで、
`j[0] = 11;`
は、ｊが指す本体の０番目の要素を１１に更新するという意味です。
ｊを使って本体の内容を変更していることになります。
それで、この操作後は
ｊ→｛[１１，２，３，４], length, ...}
になります。（０番目の要素１は１１で置き換えられた）

`j[]={0,9,8,7}`
このような書き方は初期化の時(変数名を定義する時に)のみできる（と考えて下さい）
[ ]は、変数名と数値を伴って
`変数名[数値]`の様に書いて、
「変数の保持している「数値」番目の要素１つ」を意味するので、
それに対して{数値, 数値, 数値...}のような複数の値を指定しようとするのは意味が合いません。
（他の言語では１つの数値でなく範囲を指定できるようなものがあります）
また、`arraycopy`(配列のコピー)とか`fill`のような複数の要素を対象とするようなメソッドがあります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
まだいまいちよくわからないのですが、i = 7と　j[0] =  11はなにが違うのでしょうか。もともと　int i = 5とj[]= {1, 2, 3,4}と
`class CallByValue{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  int i   = 5;
  int j[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("abcde");

  display(i, j, sb);

  a(i, j, sb);

  display(i, j, sb);
 }`
ここで決めているなら　j[0] =11と記述しても 11ではなく１とあらわれると思うのですが。
j[0]=11は　j[]={1,2,3,4}と最初に記述されているから参照が変更されたということになって問題ないということですか？
ためしにj[0]=11ではなく j[]={0,9,8,7}と記述したのですがエラーがでます。
これは一つずつ変更しなければいけないとういことでしょうか？
またint i = 7はエラーがでず　j[]={0,9.8,7}はどうしてエラーがでるのでしょうか。

Comment: @user10197   説明を追加してみました。「`j[0] =11;`が配列の要素を変更する。」というのはいいでしょうか。 呼び出した関数側でそれで変更がされないというのは、配列が「値型」と考えているということですが、配列は「参照型」です。

Comment: 考えが正しいかまだわかりませんがイメージはつかめました。ありがとうございます。配列は苦手だったのですが考え方が間違っているきがしました。もう少し掘り下げて学んでいきます。